# Getting values of dynamic int array in struct using pointer

Tags: c

I am trying to get the elements from pointer array in a struct. Not sure if I am doing it the right way.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    typedef struct _str
    {
        int *a;
    } _str;


    main()
    {
        _str s[]={
            {1000,2000},
            {3000,4000,5000}
            };

        printf("%d\n", s[0].a);
        printf("%d\n", s[0].a + 1); /* Gives me 1004 instead of 2000 */

        printf("%d\n", s[1].a);
        printf("%d\n", s[1].a + 1); /* Gives me 3004 instead of 4000 */
    }
```

Comment: It's because you declared the struct field as an `int *`.

Comment: I don't have a final answer because I am unsure what you are trying to do. But the reason you are seeing the results you see is because you defined a struct (`_str`) that contains a pointer (an address). You then defined an array of them with values `{1000, 2000}` and `{3000, 4000, 5000}`. Remember, these are pointers (address). In the computer, an address points to a 32-bit value (in this case). So when you print `s[0].a + 1` you are printing the first address (`s[0].a` - which is set to 1000) incremented by 1 pointer value (which is 4 bytes) so you get 1004. Similar issue for `s[1].a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code does not compile cleanly:

```
$ gcc -O3   -g      -std=c99   -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition     wd.c -o wd  
wd.c:9:5: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [enabled by default]
wd.c:9:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
wd.c: In function ‘main’:
wd.c:9:5: warning: old-style function definition [-Wold-style-definition]
wd.c:12:13: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
wd.c:12:13: warning: (near initialization for ‘s[0].a’) [enabled by default]
wd.c:12:13: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
wd.c:12:13: warning: (near initialization for ‘s[0]’) [enabled by default]
wd.c:13:13: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
wd.c:13:13: warning: (near initialization for ‘s[1].a’) [enabled by default]
wd.c:13:13: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
wd.c:13:13: warning: (near initialization for ‘s[1]’) [enabled by default]
wd.c:13:13: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
wd.c:13:13: warning: (near initialization for ‘s[1]’) [enabled by default]
wd.c:16:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]
wd.c:17:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]
wd.c:19:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]
wd.c:20:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]
$
```

Basically, that is saying "you can't do that", at least, not like that.

---

> A warning doesn't mean you can't do something.

You have to be good enough at C not to be asking this sort of question before you can afford to ignore a warning from the compiler.  In general, the compiler (or, at least, the writers of the 
compiler) know a lot more about C than you do.  Until you know enough to be able to quote chapter and verse of the standard on why something should not be given a warning, treat the compiler's word as gospel.  And never try to sneak code like that past me if I'm reviewing your code — I won't accept it.

---

The code can be rescued with C99 compound literals:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct str
{
    int *a;
} str;

int main(void)
{
    str s[] =
    {
        { (int[]){1000,2000} },
        { (int[]){3000,4000,5000} },
    };

    printf("%d\n", *(s[0].a + 0));
    printf("%d\n", *(s[0].a + 1));

    printf("%d\n", s[1].a[0]);
    printf("%d\n", s[1].a[1]);
}
```

Also, names starting with an underscore are basically reserved for the implementation.  The rules are slightly more nuanced than that, but for maximal safety, you won't create names that start with an underscore.  So, I renamed `_str` to `str`, though `str` is more usually used to mean 'string' than 'struct' in C (but I ran out of ideas for a better name).  Note the extra level of indirection needed in the `printf()` statements, written one way in the first two and another in the second two.

Comment: A warning doesn't mean you can't do something. But it certainly means you should go back and check that you really mean what you're doing.

Comment: Amazing. This is exactly the solution I was looking for. Thank you !! Thank you !!.